# appending arrays stored in dicts into a single dict in python

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have an array of dicts with the same keys, and for each key I have an array of values, just as the example bellow:

```
dict_arr = np.array([{'x': np.array([1,2,3]), 'y': np.array([1,4,9])}, {'x': np.array([4,5,6]), 'y': np.array([16,25,64])}])
```

What I need to do is to merge everything in a single dict, but by merge I mean I have to join the values of the arrays from the same key. An expected output for the example would be:

```
{'x': array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.]), 'y': array([ 1.,  4.,  9., 16., 25., 64.])}
```

The code I did was the following:

```
new_dict = {'x': np.array([]), 'y': np.array([])}
for dict_ in dict_arr:
    for key, value in dict_.items():
        new_dict[key] = np.append(new_dict[key], value)
print(new_dict)
```

and it gives me the expected output, but I wonder if there is a smarter way of doing this where I just merge the 'x' from all dicts instead of iterating over each one in every key and value and updating the value of my new dict.

**Note:** my real array of dicts is generated by a data acquisition board that can't acquire more than 1024 data per channel, so every dict on the list, except by the last one, has from one to three arrays with 1024 floats values each, and the number of dicts I have is typically in the order of 400 thousand.

Comment: numpy arrays are really not intended for this sort of data structure. And looping sounds like your best options...

Comment: I also must point out that `dict_array` is something that doesn't make sense. Putting Python objects in a `numpy.ndarray` is basically creating a *less efficient* Python list. What I would do, if the data can be huge, is use a list so you have something like `{'x':[...], ...}` so you can efficiently grow that list, then finally convert to a numpy array internally if you must. Because `np.append(new_dict[key], value)`  in a loop is an anti-pattern

Comment: In any case, there is no way to do what you want that doesn't involve iteration

Answer (score 2):

List append is faster than repeated `np.append`:

```
In [44]: dict_arr = np.array([{'x': np.array([1,2,3]), 'y': np.array([1,4,9])}, {'x': np.array([4,5,6]), 'y': np
    ...: .array([16,25,64])}])
In [45]: new_dict={'x':[], 'y':[]}
In [46]: for dict in dict_arr:
    ...:     for key,value in dict.items():
    ...:         new_dict[key].append(value)
    ...: 
In [47]: new_dict
Out[47]: 
{'x': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])],
 'y': [array([1, 4, 9]), array([16, 25, 64])]}
In [48]: newer = {key:np.hstack(value) for key,value in new_dict.items()}
In [49]: newer
Out[49]: {'x': array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 'y': array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 64])}
```

`defaultdict` can streamline this kind of dictionary build:

```
In [55]: from collections import defaultdict
In [56]: dd = defaultdict(list)
In [58]: for dict in dict_arr:
    ...:     for k,v in dict.items():
    ...:         dd[k].append(v)
    ...: 
In [59]: dd
Out[59]: 
defaultdict(list,
            {'x': [array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])],
             'y': [array([1, 4, 9]), array([16, 25, 64])]})
In [60]: newer = {key:np.hstack(value) for key,value in dd.items()}
In [61]: newer
Out[61]: {'x': array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 'y': array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 64])}
```

Since keys are the same, we can use `values`:

```
In [54]: list(zip(*[list(dict.values()) for dict in dict_arr]))
Out[54]: [(array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6])), (array([1, 4, 9]), array([16, 25, 64]))]
```

and considating:

```
In [63]: [np.hstack(i) for i in zip(*[list(dict.values()) for dict in dict_arr])]
Out[63]: [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 64])]
```

This still needs to put back into `dict` form

```
In [67]: {k:v for k,v in zip(dict_arr[0], Out[63])}
Out[67]: {'x': array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 'y': array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 64])}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this will be more performant for your use-case  (in fact, there's a good chance it'll be slower since we're still looping...), but I recommend trying and timing it on your full data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_arr = np.array([{'x': np.array([1,2,3]), 'y': np.array([1,4,9])}, {'x': np.array([4,5,6]), 'y': np.array([16,25,64])}])

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dict_arr)
df.apply(np.hstack, result_type='reduce').to_dict()

# {'x': array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 'y': array([ 1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 64])}
```